# C# IL code to Add value to Dictionary

Tags: c#, il

I have a dynamic method that takes a `DataRecord` and maps the data  to an object of a certain type.

sourced from [DynamicMethod_ILGenerator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DynamicMethod_ILGenerator.aspx)

The objects have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,object>` to hold any properties in the DataRecord that cannot be bound.

However I cannot seem to be able to work out how to add these to the Dictionary.

I know I have to call `Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, addMethod)` on the dictionary but no matter what I try I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
public static Load CreateBuilder(IDataRecord dataRecord)
    {
        var dynamicBuilder = new DynamicBuilder<T>();

        var method = new DynamicMethod("DynamicCreate", typeof(T), new[] { typeof(IDataRecord) }, typeof(T), true);
        var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

        var result = generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, result);


        // Dictionary to store.
        var dictType = typeof (Dictionary<string, object>);
        var dict = typeof(T).GetProperty("CustomFields");
        var addMethod = dictType.GetMethod("Add");

        for (var i = 0; i < dataRecord.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(dataRecord.GetName(i));
            var endIfLabel = generator.DefineLabel();

            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
            {
                var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DbIgnore), true) as DbIgnore[];
                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0) continue;

                bool isNullable = false;
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("nullable"))
                    isNullable = true;

                Type _type = dataRecord.GetFieldType(i);

                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, IsDbNullMethod);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue, endIfLabel);

                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, GetValueMethod);

                if (isNullable)
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, GetNullableType(_type));
                else
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, _type);

                //generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, dataRecord.GetFieldType(i));
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());

                generator.MarkLabel(endIfLabel);
            } else {
                  // How-To Add to Dictionary
            }
        }

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Load)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Load));
    }
```

Comment: I cannot work out how to reference the  Dictionary on the object  to call the addMethod.   I can create a new  dicitonary 
` generator.DeclareLocal(dictType);        
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, dictType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);`  and add the values to that succefully, but don't know how to reference the dictionary on the  class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside your loop, fetch the `Dictionary` reference from your object into a local variable.

Inside the loop, push the local variable holding the dictionary variable, key, and value onto the stack, then emit `callvirt` to the `Add(TKey, TValue)` method.

Comment: Thanks I am almost there,  I can  get  it to work if  I create a new dictionary and add values in the loop  i.e                  `generator.DeclareLocal(dictType);  
      
  generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, dictType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);`

but cannot seem to work out the correct syntax to access the one on the class.

Comment: @rqmedes: Without knowing how your class is structured, I can't be sure, but I guess you need to read from the `CustomFields` property?  Try `the_dict = generator.DeclareLocal(dictType); generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result); generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, dict.GetGetMethod()); generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, the_dict);`